# MySQL blocking access to all but a couple of databases only on certain IP address

Tags: mysql

So, a couple of days ago, our master instance of MySQL started blocking me from accessing all but a couple of databases but only when connecting from a specific IP address. I can connect and see all the databases when connecting from any other IP address and I can connect and see all databases when connecting to a slave instance. Credentials are the same regardless. I've never seen anything like this.

Comment: `SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user` - see if you have multiple records for your user, one for `%` as a host and one specific for the ip/host you're connecting from

Comment: Yes! There are multiple records - one specific to the IP that I'm having problems with. How would that extra record have gotten there?

Comment: Did you able to access any single DB on master? Where is your MySQL master installed? somewhere in cloud?

Comment: Yeah, I could access two DBs on master. I was using MySQL Workbench. Not sure if it could have possibly freaked out and created this rogue user. Anyway, deleting the privileges, then dropping the user solved the problem. I can now connect as the version of the user created with the host wildcard (%). Not sure which answer to mark as solved.

Answer (score 2):

To gain access to all databases you need to run these commands as a privileged user (eg on the machine itself):

```
grant all privileges on *.* to YOUR_USER_ID@REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS_YOU_WANT_TO_BE_ALLOWED;
flush privileges;
```

To get the YOUR_USER_ID@REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS_YOU_WANT_TO_BE_ALLOWED run the select user(); command. This will let you know how you are accessing the database, you can grant privileges accordingly

Comment: It's already set to allow access on all hosts. This was working fine a few days ago.

Comment: Please run the select user(); command. This will let you know how you are accessing the database, you can grant privileges accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you'll want to do to start exploring this problem is:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html

```
show grants for 'user'@'host';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try run this script

GRANT ALL ON *.* to user@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

It would allow you to access from any IP Address and any machines and access all databases.

Good Luck :)